# python: copy values of big array in smaller arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem,
where I would like to copy values of X a ( n x n ) array into smaller array A, B , C, D
here is my current code.

```
X = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
n = len(X)
n_by_2 = n // 2
A = [[]]
B = [[]]
C = [[]]
D = [[]]
"""
X = [
    A<--     B<--
    [1,2,  | 3,4],
    [5,6,  | 7,8],
    -------|-------
    D<--   | C<--
    [9,10, | 11,12],
    [13,14,| 15,16]
    ]
"""
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X[i])):
        if (i >= 0 and i < n_by_2) and (j >= 0 and j < n_by_2):
            #copy 1st quadrent values to A
            #A[i][j] = X[i][j]
        if (i >= 0 and i < n_by_2) and (j >= n_by_2 and j < n):
            #copy 2nd quadrent values to B
            #B[i][j] = X[i][j]
        if (i >= n_by_2 and i < n) and (j >= 0 and j < n_by_2):
            #copy 3rd quadrent values to C
            #C[i][j] = X[i][j]
        if (i >= n_by_2 and i < n) and (j >= n_by_2 and j < n):
            #copy 4th quadrent values to D
            #D[i][j] = X[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you cannot add a new item `x` to an empty list `l` by doing.
`l[0] = x`.  This only works if the list already has a length greater than 0.  In that situation, you can use the `append` method instead.

For your problem, this code will do the job:

```py
X = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
n = len(X)
n_by_2 = n // 2
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
for i in range(n_by_2):
    A.append(X[i][:n_by_2])
    B.append(X[i][n_by_2-1:-1])
for i in range(n_by_2):
    C.append(X[i + n_by_2][:n_by_2])
    D.append(X[i + n_by_2][n_by_2-1:-1])

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
```